# Resizing div via mouse is too slow/delayed

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

I have a website with a navigation panel and the width is handled by a css variable. Now I want to resize the panel by dragging the border. It does work but for some reason, it has a delay. I actualy expect the panel to resize itself in real time. [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qky6h.png)

I googled a little and found throttle and debouncing functions but it has no effect on my problem. I assume that I am working on the css variable rather then the actual css property of my panel causes performance issues but I dont have prove of this and I would like to do it this way because I also have my button and the collapse function of this panel bond to this css variable. I can give more information if im too cryptic here. i just cant copy the whole thing, so I hope the code already tells you something. The variables name is '--sidebarWidth'.

So my question is: Why do I have such a huge delay/Why isnt the border following my mouse in realtime?

This is the javascript code:

```
var mousedown = false;
var slide = false;
var relative = null;
var initialsidebarWidth = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--sidebarWidth');

const throttleFunction = (func, delay) => {
    let prev = 0;
    return (...args) => {
        let now = new Date().getTime();
        if (now - prev > delay) {
            prev = now;
            return func(...args);
        }
    }
}


$(window).on("mousedown", throttleFunction(() => {
    mousedown = true;
}, 50));

$(window).on("mouseup", throttleFunction(() => {
    mousedown = false;
}, 50));

$(window).on('mousemove', throttleFunction((event) => {
    let sidebarWidth = initialsidebarWidth;
    let cursorMargin = 5;
    let cursorX = event.pageX;
    let activeRangeBool = (cursorX - cursorMargin) < sidebarWidth && (cursorX + cursorMargin) > sidebarWidth;

    // Change cursor when in range
    if (activeRangeBool) {
        $("html").css('cursor', 'ew-resize');
    } else {
        $("html").css('cursor', 'auto');
    }

    // Activate slideMode
    if (activeRangeBool && mousedown) {
        slide = true;
    }
    if (!mousedown) {
        slide = false;
    }

    if (slide) {
        if (relative == null) {
            relative = cursorX;
        }
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--sidebarWidth', parseInt(initialsidebarWidth) + (cursorX - relative));
    } else {
        initialsidebarWidth = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--sidebarWidth');
        relative = null;
    }
}, 100));
```

I hope you can help me and thx in advance.

Comment: Hello, why do you use throttleFunction ? Do you need a delay ? Parameter delay in this function is not define when you call it...

Comment: @kopacabana : No I dont. I just thought maybe It reduces the load a little^^... I just rebuild it quick on fiddle but it doesnt have any delay: https://jsfiddle.net/wnxd1zs2/18/ .... Ill delete the throttle function quick but as i said, it has no effect.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wnxd1zs2/19/ ... Its weird. It works just fine on fiddle. On my website its stuttering and has a big delay.

Comment: Ok so, i copied the whole frontend into fiddle and now its also slow on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wnxd1zs2/23/

Comment: ... Ok I have the solution... i had a transition of half a second.... It was for my collapsible function....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not visible from here but I had a transition of 0,5s set because of the collapse function of the same panel. The delay is gone now